# WordPress redirect specific user after login

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, redirect, woocommerce

I am trying to redirect a specific user from the admin dashboard to the WooCommerce order page after successful login.

My code kinda seems to be working. The redirect is happening but it displays an error message "Sorry you do not have permission to view this page". I am 100% sure that the user has permission to view that particular page.

I am somewhat thinking that this is because the redirect is happening before the actual session is set. Any idea how to solve this?

My code:

```
function my_login_redirect($redirect_to, $request, $user){
    if($user->user_login == 'monitor') {
        return home_url("/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order/");
    }
}
add_filter("login_redirect", "my_login_redirect", 10, 3);
```

Comment: i think you should install https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/ this plugin and confirm user permission. this plugin will provide a solution to set permission for perticular page also

Comment: positive that the user has permission to view the page. If I log in without the function posted and view the page, the user can view the page without any problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure about permission, remove last slash and try again.

```
return home_url("/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=shop_order");
```

Comment: Thank you. Removing the last slash seems to have solved issue :)